# How to load selected option in dropdown menu without having to reload the page?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a simple form where users can submit a dial code and phone number! When adding a new instance in the database it works fine. However, I have some issues with editing an existing instance. In the database I save `dialcode` as `integer` and `phone number` as `integer` (e.g. `213` will store the dial code of Algeria and `1234567890` the phone number)

I managed to sort of solve this, but still have an issue! This works as expected but I will have to reload the page to make it execute. How to implement the code below once and only once, and when the page is loaded similarly with the rest of the data (name, email, twitter, phone_number)?

In other words how to set the selected option in the dropdown menu since I know what the value is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  //select tag
  let country_code = document.getElementById("country_code_dropdown");    
  
  //set correct option according to numeric value:
  window.onload = function(){
    //get current dial code value:
    let dialCode = document.getElementById("country_phone_code_input").value; //357

    //Loop through
    Array.from(document.querySelector("#country_code_dropdown").options).forEach(function(option_element) {
        let option_value = option_element.value;

        if(option_value == dialCode){ //if value matches:
          option_element.selected = true; //set <option> to selected: true
          document.getElementById("phone_number_input").innerHTML  = "+" + option_value; //and change span
        }
    });
  };
</script>
```

---

STAGE 1:
[image]

---

STAGE 2:
[image: STAGE 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your trying to setup a classic input binding and you're running into issues with Turbolinks. Since Turbolinks performs page replacement with ajax you need to write idempotent event handlers instead of attaching the handlers directly to the elements:

```js
function handleCountryPhoneCodeInput(source) {
  let opt = source.form.querySelector(`#country_code_dropdown option[value="${source.value}"]`);
  if (opt) {
    opt.selected = true;
  } else {
    console.log('Computer says no.');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  let el = event.target;
  if (el.matches('#country_phone_code_input')) {
    handleCountryPhoneCodeInput(el);
  } else if (el.matches('#country_code_dropdown')) {
    let target = el.form.querySelector('#country_phone_code_input');
    target.value = el.value;
  }
});

// Set initial value on page load
// Use `turbolinks:load` instead if you are using turbolinks.
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  let el = document.getElementById('country_phone_code_input');
  if (el) { handleCountryPhoneCodeInput(el) };
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Access code 
    <input id="country_phone_code_input" name='user[country_phone_code_input]' value="456">
  </label>
  <label>
    Select an access code
    <select id="country_code_dropdown">
      <option value="123">123</option>
      <option value="456">456</option>
      <option value="789">789</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</form>
```

This code should be placed in your assets or packs depending on if you're using Sprockets or Webpacker. Just say no to inline script tags in Rails as it will wreck havoc with turbolinks since you have a persisentent browser session.

You could also set the initial selected value directly on the server side to avoid the select suddendly changing when the input changes.

Comment: I understood the first part I think, but I'm having trouble understanding Rails stuff. Any documentation / references? `I'm using Rails 6.1.3.2` I assume this is using Webpacker, correct????? (there is a weback folder under `config/webpack`)

Comment: Yes, Rails 6 defaults to Webpacker. The official guide [is here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html) and there are plenty of tutorials like https://dev.to/vvo/a-rails-6-setup-guide-for-2019-and-2020-hf5#webpacker-usage

Comment: Okay, I managed to create custom js files with Webpacker! But I have few questions. This code will execute for all pages! I only want to execute it with one page. and not the entire website! Also the code you provided still leads to the same problem (having to reload the page).

Comment: When I use my code it works great. but I get errors when I'm not in that page since the code is looking for a menu that doesn't exist, i.e. in home page

Comment: Just add a condition and check if the element exists. In general the whole "I just want this JS to happen on this page" approach is an anti-pattern. Think in terms of reusable modules/behaviors that you can augment any page with.

Comment: Got it, Thanks max :D

Comment: If you're using turbolinks you'll want to use `document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load',  ...` instead of `window.addEventListener('load', ...`.